# Count the repetitions of an element from a file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a one column file composed by only integer as

```
1
1
4
3
3
2
```

I want to count how many time a number appear in the file. The output file should be:

```
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 1
```

Thanks

Comment: do you know the number range of the data?

Comment: yes, I know it. the answer I hope will be as general as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{tot[$0]++} END{for (n in tot) {print n,tot[n]}} ' numbers
```